# How to move another activity after login to the facebook(facebook integration) using tabs?

Tags: android

HI Am working for the application using tabs through entire app.In that one particular tab am integrated facebook and twitter.its After clicking facebook button it shows the login screen of facebook and login success also working fine but when the login completed i want to redirect to another activity for that i used the following code in onComplete()

```
                   View view = Socialtab.group.getLocalActivityManager()  
                       .startActivity("Items", new Intent(Social.this,MainActivity.class)
                       .putExtra("name", name)
                       .putExtra("email", email)
                       .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
                       .getDecorView();
                    Socialtab.group.replaceView(view);
```

it is showing the exception at the following line

```
.startActivity("Items", new Intent(Social.this,MainActivity.class)
```

and my logcat error is follows:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.karmakexpo/com.karmakexpo.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)   
at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1524)

at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)

at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)    
at com.karmakexpo.Social.jsonParsing(Social.java:353)   
at com.karmakexpo.Social$SampleRequestListener.onComplete(Social.java:258)  
at com.karmakexpo.facebook.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:238)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:698)

at com.karmakexpo.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:56)

at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409) at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1610)
... 6 more
```

I have googled and did not get any solution please give the solution 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as using runOnUiThread :

```
  Social.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    View view = Socialtab.group.getLocalActivityManager()  
               .startActivity("Items", new Intent(Social.this,MainActivity.class)
               .putExtra("name", name)
               .putExtra("email", email)
               .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
               .getDecorView();
               Socialtab.group.replaceView(view); 
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your code in main UI thread.

try this

```
Looper.prepare();  // Initialize the current thread as a looper. This gives you a chance to create handlers that then reference this looper, before actually starting the loop. 

 View view = Socialtab.group.getLocalActivityManager()  
               .startActivity("Items", new Intent(Social.this,MainActivity.class)
               .putExtra("name", name)
               .putExtra("email", email)
               .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
               .getDecorView();
               Socialtab.group.replaceView(view); 
Looper.loop();
```